# Spring-boot app with unkown @PastOrPresent annotation

Tags: spring-boot, bean-validation

in spring-boot web-app,
when i use @PastOrPresent STS shows me this error :

*(PastOrPresent cannot be resolved to a type)*

but org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation entry is already among the dependencies.

Gradle file

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.5.9.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

group = 'com.domain'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

compileJava.options.encoding = "UTF-8"
compileTestJava.options.encoding = "UTF-8"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}


dependencies {

    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator-docs')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    runtime('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools')
    runtime('org.postgresql:postgresql')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    testCompile('org.springframework.security:spring-security-test')
}
```

**UPDATE of Gradle file**

```
...

compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'){
 exclude group: 'org.hibernate', module: 'hibernate-validator:5.3.6.Final'
}
compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:6.0.7.Final'

...

|    \--- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:5.3.6.Final -> 6.0.7.Final
|         \--- org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:6.0.7.Final
|              +--- javax.validation:validation-api:2.0.1.Final -> 1.1.0.Final
|              +--- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:3.3.0.Final -> 3.3.1.Final
|              \--- com.fasterxml:classmate:1.3.1 -> 1.3.4
```

have i some thing else to do ? while inside the entity i still have the same error. with new one : The type NotEmpty is deprecated (as shows the doc [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/6.0/api/index.html?org/hibernate/validator/constraints/NotEmpty.html))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `@PastOrPresent` constraint is a part of Bean Validation 2.0 (see [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/beanvalidation/spec/2.0/api/javax/validation/constraints/PastOrPresent.html)), while the Spring Boot is still using Hibernate Validator 5.3 by default (see the dependencies [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-validation/1.5.9.RELEASE)), which is BeanValidation 1.1. If you'd like to use this new constraint you would need to have an explicit dependency for Hibernate Validator 6.0 and exclude 5.4 version from your current dependencies.

Comment: Thx, please see original msg update, i think that i have to add explicitly `compile 'javax.validation:validation-api:2.0.1.Final'`, as it's replaced by the 1.1.0.final version under the  `org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:6.0.7.Final` node

Comment: HI, yes it seems so. As for the deprecation warning. It is expected. `@NotEmpty` was added to Bean Validation 2.0 hence the one from Hibernate Validator is deprecated in favor of the one from the spec. Just use the one from `javax.validation.constraints`